# Adjust GridView EDIT textbox size

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2005

I am using VS2005 C#

I have a GridView and I have enabled row editing.

However, I have some columns which will have a larger input, such as *Comments* column, which will contain more words.

Is there a way to adjust the textbox sizes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want control over width *and* height, as well as other properties, you can reference the TextBox in your GridView's RowDataBound event and set its height and width as well as setting the TextMode to MultiLine:

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        // Comments
        TextBox comments = (TextBox)e.Row.Cells[column_index].Controls[control_index];
        comments.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        comments.Height = 100;
        comments.Width = 400;
    }
}
```

Ensure you're referencing the edit row by checking the RowState or EditIndex, and set your column_index and control_index appropriately. For BoundFields, the control index will typically be 0.

Comment: i have set my column index, however the textbox doesn't resize after making the changes

Answer (score 2):

Set the `ItemStyle-Width` and `ControlStyle-Width`, and if you want wrap the text use `ItemStyle-Wrap`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Brissles answer is correct but DataControlRowState can have multiple states ORed together so you may need to check for edit state like this:

```
(e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) != 0
```